# Drawing a cigarette with basic shapes

Tags: android, android-drawable

I'm trying to draw a cigarette with the "ash" view being a percentage of the "smokeable" view. It needs to be a percentage because I am going to use a slider which will change the percentage of the "ash" view.

Here is what I want:

[image: Imgur]

Here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/cigarette"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/butt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:background="#ff7700" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/smokeable"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".75"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/ash"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:background="#777777"
            android:gravity="right" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In this example I want the ash to be 33% of the smokeable view. I can't figure out why this isn't working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Because I am going to have a slider where the user can select how much they smoked. The slider value can range from 1/4, 1/3, 1/2, etc. When they change the slider it will automatically change the ash width in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner `LinearLayout` needs another child `View` for the not-yet-consumed part of the cigarette. Its `layout_weight` has to be 1 - 0.33 = 0.67 in your example (the sum of the weights of both siblings always has to be 1).

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/cigarette"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titleText"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/butt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:background="#ff7700" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/smokeable"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".75"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/rest"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#cccccc"
            android:layout_weight=".67"
            />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/ash"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:background="#777777"
            android:gravity="right" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please note that while this will fix your code, the "nested weighted LinearLayout" approach isn't a good way to go, even if modern devices should not run into performance problems.

The [solution by lelloman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48038234/5015207) involving a custom `View` is much better because you need only one `View`, not two `ViewGroup`s plus three `View`s. You have one method to easily change the percentage, plus all the calculating and drawing parts are nicely encapsulated.

Answer (score 2):

I think the <s>easiest</s> cleanest way would be to make a custom `View` for you "cigarette", it would be composed of filter/smokeable/ash, each part with a different color.

So declare some styleable attributes in, say, `attrs.xml`

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CigaretteView">
        <attr name="filterColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="smokeableColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="ashColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="filterWidth" format="dimension" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

The `View` class itself:

```
class CigaretteView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : View(context, attrs) {

    companion object {
        private val DEFAULT_FILTER_COLOR = 0xffbbaa00.toInt()
        private val DEFAULT_SMOKABLE_COLOR = 0xffffffff.toInt()
        private val DEFAULT_ASH_COLOR = 0xff888888.toInt()
        private val DEFAUALT_FILTER_WIDTH_PX = 120
    }

    private val filterPaint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    private val smokeablePaint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    private val ashPaint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)

    private var filterWidthPx = DEFAUALT_FILTER_WIDTH_PX

    private val rect = Rect()

    var smokedPercent = 0f
    set(value) {
        field = value
        invalidate()
    }

    init {
        val a = context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CigaretteView, 0, 0)

        var filterColor = DEFAULT_FILTER_COLOR
        var smokeableColor = DEFAULT_SMOKABLE_COLOR
        var ashColor = DEFAULT_ASH_COLOR

        try {
            filterColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CigaretteView_filterColor, filterColor)
            smokeableColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CigaretteView_smokeableColor, smokeableColor)
            ashColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CigaretteView_ashColor, ashColor)
            filterWidthPx = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CigaretteView_filterWidth, filterWidthPx)
        } finally {
            a.recycle()
        }

        filterPaint.color = filterColor
        smokeablePaint.color = smokeableColor
        ashPaint.color = ashColor
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        rect.set(0, 0, filterWidthPx, height)
        canvas.drawRect(rect, filterPaint)

        val leftOver = (width - filterWidthPx).toFloat()
        val ashStartPoint = (width - leftOver * smokedPercent).toInt()

        rect.set(filterWidthPx, 0, ashStartPoint, height)
        canvas.drawRect(rect, smokeablePaint)

        rect.set(ashStartPoint, 0, width, height)
        canvas.drawRect(rect, ashPaint)
    }
}
```

Your xml layout would be simplified to

```
<com.example.CigaretteView
    android:id="@+id/cigaretteView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    app:filterWidth="48dp"
    app:filterColor="#ffbbaa00"
    app:smokeableColor="#ffffffff"
    app:ashColor="#ff888888"/>
```

And then you could simply assign ash percent value with

```
myCigaretteView.smokedPercent = percent
```

where `percent` goes from 0 (cigarette is intact) to 1 (cigarette completely smoked).

Comment: This may not be "the easiest" way but I like it very much :)

Comment: I mean it's the easiest way because using dummy `View`s doesn't look like a viable option to me, it would be nuked in code review, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Given that all three elements are in line, you only want and need one `LinearLayout` parent:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/cigarette"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/butt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:background="#ff7700" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/smokeable"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="65"
        android:background="#cccccc" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/ash"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:background="#777777" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I want the ash to be a percentage of the smokeable view, so that it can easily be changed programatically via a slider.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest thing I can think of that does what you need:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:background="#777777"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/butt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="#ff7700"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/smokeable"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        android:transformPivotX="0px"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now you can call `smokeable.setScaleX()` with any percentage to get the desired result.